# Only catch certain word lengths

Tags: java, string-length

If I got a .txt file named words.txt and I want to catch the words to input them into an arraylist how do I do that.  I know buffered reader exists but I dont quite get how to use it. All words are seperated by a space or an enter key. It has to then for example filter out words that are not 4 characters long and place the 4 long words in an arraylist to use later.
For example I got this txt file :

```
one > gets ignored
two > gets ignored
three > gets ignored
four >  caught and put into for example arraylist
five > 4 long so gets caught and put into arraylist
six > ignored
seven > ignored
eight >  ignored
nine >  caught because its 4 char long
ten > ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [streams](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/architect-streams-pt2.html) and [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("words.txt");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            List<String> list = lines.filter(word -> word.length() == 4)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **words.txt** file:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

And running the above code, using the above file, prints the following:

```
[four, five, nine]
```

Alternatively, you can use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path source = Paths.get("words.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source)) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String word = scanner.nextLine();
                if (word.length() == 4) {
                    list.add(word);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both the above versions of class `Main` use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Yet another way is to use class [java.io.BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) (since you mentioned it in your question).

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("words.txt");
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.length() == 4) {
                    list.add(line);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use the arraylist made in this static class in like another void method  to pick something out of it and do some stuff with it? Would it require to make the arraylist in another way like declaring it outside of the static borders so you can use it anywhere?